# How can I get the length of a function's output if it has more than one output using func()?

Tags: python

I have a list of functions to be called like:

`list_of_functions = [func1, func2, func3]`

Each function output either a single list of dicts, e.g. `context_dicts` or it might output something else like:

```
context_dicts = func1
context_dicts, output1, output2 = func2
```

In another part of the script, I'm interested in the length of `context_dicts` of every function after they are executed so I have:

```
def get_summary():
   counts = []

   for func in list_of_functions:
      if callable(func):
         if something:
            count = len(func())
            counts.append({'count': count})

   return counts
```

But if my output is simply `context_dicts` that's fine and I'll get the actual length of the list, but if I'm calling `func2` then `len(func())` will actually give me 3 as it's the number of outputs.
How can I always get the length of `context_dicts` no matter what?

Comment: Have you written the functions? Or you are using someone else's functions? Basically - can you change what the function returns?

Comment: So the functions returns either single dict or list of some values, where the first value is the dict you are looking for?
Does it make sense to check the type of returned value? `type(value) == list` or `type(value) == dict`?

Comment: If the `context_dicts` is single list of dicts, then you can check if the first element is dict or list: `type(context_dicts[0]) == dict`

Answer (score 0):

@PavelBotsman gave me an idea on how to look for an answer so I'm just testing if the output is a tuple or note (because the structure of the function doesn't output a list) so basically:

```
if isinstance(func(), tuple):
   len(func()[0]) 
else:
   len(func())
```

Thank you